# Hidden field isn't giving correct value in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having add_subtract partial

```
<% if Promotion.max_discount_rate_future(product, current_user) > 0 %>
  <div class="price" id="price" data-price="<%= display_two_decimal((product.trade_price * (1 - (Promotion.max_discount_rate_future(product, current_user) /100.0))) * product.min_item_order) %>" data-quantity="<%= product.quantity %>">£<%= display_two_decimal((product.trade_price * (1 - (Promotion.max_discount_rate_future(product, current_user) /100.0))) * product.min_item_order) %></div>
<% else %>
  <div class="price" id="price" data-price="<%= display_two_decimal(product.trade_price * product.min_item_order) %>" data-quantity="<%= product.quantity %>">£<%= display_two_decimal(product.trade_price * product.min_item_order) %></div>
<% end %>
<div class="subtract" id='subtract'>-</div>
<div class="number" data-multiple="<%= product.min_item_order %>" id='number'><%= product.min_item_order %></div>
<div class="add" id='add'>+</div>
```

After that, I have add to cart partial

```
<%= button_to buyer_basket_line_item_index_path, method: :post, form_class: 'no-margin', class: 'btn btn-primary add_to_basket', params: { product_id: product.id, hidden_quantity_submit: product.min_item_order }, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } do %>

<% end %>
```

The problem is, when I add or subtract an item in the product card, it behaves perfect. But when I add/subtract one item and without clicking on add to cart button, if I add/subtract the second item, and then again click on add to cart of first item, I get second cards' total value in the controller. How to solve this issue?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAgNi.png)

Here, I first increased items of first card to 3 and then increased items of second card to 5. But when I click on add to cart on first card, it takes 5 as a quantity. It's taking the recent one and not according to the product.

Comment: So you render this partial several times on the same page? It doesn't mix well with hardcoded ids. There should be only one element with a given ID on the page. Your add/subtract code (which you didn't show) likely doesn't handle this.

Comment: Also, there seems to be no hidden fields here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The first partial itself is add_subtract partial. And yes this partial renders in a loop of products.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `params: { product_id: product.id, hidden_quantity_submit: product.min_item_order }` creates hidden inputs. But for anything this complex I would really use `form_with/form_for` instead of `button_to` which just makes it extremely hard to figure out what the code is doing. The end result is the same.